# iOS 7 UIAlertView interface orientation of view in background does not update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

i have an App with landscape and portrait interface orientation. Everything works fine but when i show an alertview and change the interface orientation only the status bar does update its orientation but not the view itself. (status bar is landscape but view still in portrait)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Okay i found out that this somehow only occurs to UIAlertViews which are shown in viewDidLoad or applicationDidFinishLaunchinWithOptions:.

Comment: For me UIAlertview initiated from button action, for me issue still exist. can you tell me the issue fix?

Comment: No sorry didn't found a solution either

Comment: Fixed. In my case i was accidentally doing self = [self init] instead of self = [super init]. Interestingly this affects only when alert view is on the screen.

Comment: @Galaxy didn't solve my issue

Comment: @Nilz11 By any chance are you swapping window's root view controller after the initial configuration in app delegate?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Just having a simple UITabbarController as RootView Controller of UIWindows and calling an UIAlertView when a view of the UITabbar shows (in viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller)

Comment: Did anyone ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having a similar issue, as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833129/prevent-alertview-from-auto-rotating