# Prevent AlertView from auto rotating

Tags: ios, uialertview, autorotate, device-orientation

The launch page of my app is set to *portrait* only with this little bit of code:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait ;
}
```

When the app launches a `UIAlertView` appears for username and password entry.
The method to display it is called from `viewWillAppear`.

This worked fine for *iOS6* but since *iOS7*, if I switch the device to landscape, the main view remains in portrait but the the alert view and keyboard rotate to landscape.
A further bizarre quirk is that when I switch back to portrait, only the keyboard switches back (in truncated form), leaving the alert frozen in landscape mode:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this?

**-EDIT-**

The autorotate code is called in a separate category:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) return NO;
    else return YES;
}
```

@end

**-EDIT 2-**

I've also tried creating a Category on `UIAlertView` but it's never called:

```
@implementation UIAlertView (Orientation)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

**-EDIT 3-**

I'm not sure how relevant this is but here's the code for showing the alert:

```
- (void)alertWithMessage:(NSString *)theMessage
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                    message:theMessage
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Login"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    UITextField *nameField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: You say "when the app launches". When exactly is that? In what method do you call `alertWithMessage:`?

Comment: It's called from `viewWillAppear`. I'll update the question.

Comment: Try doing it in `viewDidAppear:`. Not sure if that's going to make a difference, but I've seen weirdness like this before.

Comment: Thank you! Had tried it in `viewDidLoad` and misread your comment thinking that's what you meant. Just tried it in `viewDidAppear` and it worked. +1 for your comments and if you post them as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this in `viewDidAppear:`. I've seen weird behavior like this before because view layouts are not entirely defined yet. In `viewDidAppear:`, everything is set and laid out, so there shouldn't be any problems at that point.

Comment: Thanks. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with implementing `shouldAutorotate` ? You can do in your case :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) return NO;
    else return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is this method implemented in the view controller managing the UIAlertView? Is this view controller the root view controller of your app?

Comment: Yes, I've a category which overrides the `shouldAutorotate` methods in the root view controller, so `shouldAutorotate` is called in the category but still doesn't prevent rotation. I'll edit my question to include the category code.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this, but the alert was being shown from the AppDelegate. After reading Scott Berrevoet's answer about view layouts not being entirely defined yet I added a very slight delay before showing the alert dialog to give everything some time to set up and that fixed the problem.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self.updateAlert show];
});
```